# how to display core data on cell in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

In my app i want to store data in core data and that data should be display on cell of `UITableView`.

Now I had successfully store the data in core data.

Now how to display all my data on cell of `UITableView`?

Now I had edited some TasksViewController.m code

TasksViewController.h

```
@interface TasksViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *tasks;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *taskTaskNameArray,*taskColorTagArray,*taskProjectName,*taskStartingTimeArray,*taskCompletingTimeArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;

@end
```

TasksViewController.m

```
@implementation TasksViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Task"];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"task_name",@"color_tag",@"project_name",@"completing_date",@"starting_date",nil]];

    NSError *error = nil;
_arrayTasks = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    _taskTaskNameArray = [self.arrayTasks valueForKey:@"task_name"];
    _taskColorTagArray = [self.arrayTasks valueForKey:@"color_tag"];
    _taskProjectNameArray = [self.arrayTasks valueForKey:@"project_name"];
    _taskStartingTimeArray = [self.arrayTasks valueForKey:@"starting_date"];
    _taskCompletingTimeArray = [self.arrayTasks valueForKey:@"completing_date"];

   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _arrayTasks.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TasksTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TasksTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.lblTaskName.text = [_arrayTask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
    cell.lblColorTag.text = [_arrayTask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblProjectName.text = [_arrayTask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblCompletingDate.text = [_arrayTask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblStartingDate.text = [_arrayTask objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Tasks.h

```
@interface Tasks : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *taskTaskName,*taskColorTag,*taskProjectName,*taskStartingDate,*taskCompletingDate;

@end
```

Task.m

```
@implementation Tasks

@dynamic taskTaskName;
@dynamic taskColorTag;
@dynamic taskProjectName;
@dynamic taskStartingDate;
@dynamic taskCompletingDate;

@end
```

TasksTableViewCell.h

```
@interface TasksTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTaskName;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblColorTag;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblProjectName;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStartingTime;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCompletingTime;

@end
```

TasksTableViewCell.m

```
@implementation TasksTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

I had tried this code but it is not working and not display data on cell of `UITableView`.

I had edited some code in **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** of TasksTableViewController.m .

**I had store data of core in array and whole Task table is store in arrayTask and its attribute are also stores in different different array like taskname in _taskTaskNameArray and like that...**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The only mistake is in the `configurecell` function. Change this `Tasks *tasks = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` to `Tasks *tasks = [self.tasks objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Done But not Working @iphonic

Comment: You never actually instantiate the FRC, and once created you need to call `performFetch` on your fetched results controller.  This is normally done in the getter method, `fetchedResultsController`, just before returning.  Once you do this, the issues pointed out by @Justlike in his answer will come to light.

Comment: Sorry But Didn't got what are you saying @pbasdf

Comment: You never assign a value to _fetchedResultsController, so it's nil throughout.  Even after you create it, you need to use `perfromFetch` to get the data from the store.  Not at my Mac now, so I haven't got sample code to hand, but I think Apple's class reference for `NSFetchedResultsController` has the necessary code.

Comment: Hey @pbasdf  i had edited my some code in TaskViewController.m but same problem

Comment: Hey @iphonic i had edited my some code in TaskViewController.m but same problem

Comment: @ParagBharambe That code looks completely different.  Please can you explain precisely what happens: do any cells appear?  If they appear, are they empty?  Are the tableview datasource/delegate methods executed (put NSLog() statements in to check)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. update NSSortDescriptor like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *taskNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"taskTaskName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *subTaskDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"taskColorTag" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *startingDateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"taskStartingDate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *completingDateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"taskCompletingDate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *projectNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"taskProjectName" ascending:YES];
// ...
```

> Sort key should be same with property name.

2. use **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:** instead of **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**: to make sure the cell isn't nil.

Answer (score -1):

Change array to `self.tasks` and index to `indexpath.row`

```
- (void)configureCell:(TasksTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell to show the book's title
    Tasks *tasks = [self.tasks objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];

    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Done But not Working  @MS

Comment: Hey @MS. i had edited my some code in TaskViewController.m but same problem

Comment: @ParagBharambe What is array count of '_arrayTasks' and others ?

Comment: @ParagBharambe 'return cell' is missing. Have you added ?

Comment: Ya array of count is _arrayTask of Enitity. And I had store all attribute in different array.